# Package or namespace load failed,the vctrs package is not properly installed

Tags: r

I have tried to load some packages, I updated, and saw no positive resolution. So I tried reinstalling them all by deleting and installing the specific packages I had trouble with, however the issue did not get solved.

```
> library(tidyverse)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'vctrs', details:
  call: NULL
  error: The vctrs package is not properly installed.
x The DLL version (0.3.5) does not correspond to the package version (0.3.7).
i Please update vctrs to the latest version.
i Updating packages on Windows requires precautions:
  <https://github.com/jennybc/what-they-forgot/issues/62>
```

Comment: Run `install.packages("vctrs")`

Comment: If @Phil's does't work, run `remove.packages("vctrs")` first and then try `install.packages("vctrs")`

Comment: It worked, thank you very much